# maven jar plugin cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven, m2eclipse

I am trying to learn hyperjaxb3, so I downloaded the zip file containing the maven project for the `purchase order tutorial` for hibernate and maven [from this link](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/HJ3/Home), and then imported it into eclipse as a new maven project.  But I am getting the following error message in the pom.xml:

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:  
org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3:maven-hyperjaxb3-plugin:0.5.6:generate (execution: default, phase: generate-sources)
```

I tried to resolve this error message by adding the following dependency to the pom.xml, which I found [at this link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-jar-plugin/2.3.2):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

But I am still getting the same error.  There is no stack trace because I have not tried to compile the program.  It is a compile error message that eclipse gives in the pom.

**How can I resolve this error?**

The complete pom.xml can be viewed [by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/qduszUPZ5i4Av4RGhNUs?b=YSsu6Jn5a3vlXHGZtuxb).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugins with executions goals need to be moved to `<pluginManagement>` to get rid of this error. It should look like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- plugins  --> 
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!-- plugins with execution goals --> 
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: Thank you! How do I deal with the other plugins that do not have execution goals?  The pom is in a link you can click from my original post above.  It is a small pom, but there are other plugins that do not have execution goals.

Comment: I updated the answer. You can keep them in <plugins>

Comment: Thank you.  +1.  I think that solved it.  I need to work with it for a while to confirm before marking it as the answer.